# Re-exporting MUI components from React component library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook, rollup

I'm setting up a component library with React, Storybook, Typescript and Material UI. One of the main targets of the library is to re-export components that are imported from MUI (with a bit of config on top of them). I stumbled upon an issue where one of the components is not being rendered as intended when used in another React app. The component I am talking about is the `Stepper` component. Below is what I have now:

Stepper.tsx

```
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import MUIStepper, { StepperProps } from '@mui/material/Stepper';

const Stepper = (props: StepperProps) => {
    return (
        <Stack sx={{ width: '100%' }} spacing={4}>
            <MUIStepper {...props}></MUIStepper>
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default Stepper
```

This is going to be built as a library using rollup.
I am not going to paste the entire rollup config here, but these are the plugins the config is using:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
```

After the process of building and publishing the library to an npm registry, I am trying to use it in some other React application, but some of the styles/internal components of the Stepper are totally missing (ex: active step css, step connectors etc.). The usage of the Stepper component is the same as in the official docs and it works perfectly with the original Stepper component.

Can you think of any configuration I am missing? It looks like something is lost along the way while building the library, but not sure what. Either that or the children components do not receive props properly.
I can provide further insight into this if necessary, but I didn't want to clutter the post anymore that it already is.

Answer (score 1):

The `Stepper` component expects two or more `Step` components as children. To fix this, you need to pass `props.children` to the Stepper component.

```
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import MUIStepper, { StepperProps } from '@mui/material/Stepper';

const Stepper = (props: StepperProps) => {
    return (
        <Stack sx={{ width: '100%' }} spacing={4}>
            <MUIStepper {...props}>{props.children}</MUIStepper>
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default Stepper;
```

Comment: That's not the case I'm afraid. Something else is getting messed up during the library build. I've extracted the same component in the same project I am using it and it works fine. Will have to further look into it. I am most probably missing some rollup config/babel transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:
It looks like this behavior si encountered whenever we deal with components that use the Context API internally. Somehow, the context gets messed up if we use the root component from our library and other descendant components from MUI. Simply importing and re-exporting descendant components and using them from owr library as well fixes this issue, although I would want to avoid that. Until then, I created an issue on the github page to see if it is a bug on their side or just an intended behavior which affects my case here.
All in all, it is not really a rollup config issue. Transpilation and bundling work as intended.

Issue link: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33320

Answer (score 0):

Had the same kind of issue with MUI button. I was trying to re-export the button component with some custom theming and styling.  I got the "dispatcher is null" error without even using any dispatchers. I got this fixed by changing the package.json. I have emptied the "dependencies" object and added everything to "devDependencies". Then I have added "peerDependencies" object as well. This fixed my issue after two long sleepless nights.